# Copy text file error

Tags: c, text

I wrote this program to read a paragraph written in a file in a text file and copy it to another file. The program worked ok but when I open the copy file it had a garbage character in the end. I attach my source code below.
I keep having the "ÿ" character at EOF. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch = NULL;
    fp = fopen("vanban.txt", "r");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        printf("Mo File thanh cong!\n");
        printf("Doc File thanh cong!\n");
        char ch = NULL;
        FILE *fp1;
        fp1 = fopen("vanban1.txt", "w");
        do
        {
            if (ch <= 255 && ch >= 0)
            {
                ch = fgetc(fp);
                fputc(ch, fp1);
            }
        } while (ch != EOF);
        fclose(fp1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FIle khong mo duoc hoac khong ton tai.\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Read it out loud. Check a character is valid. If it is read another character and write it to file. See the problem?

Comment: Quick quiz: Is `char` signed or unsigned? What values could `ch` take on that you need to test for? What values are invalid that you want to exclude? Could this code take the form of a `switch` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
char ch = NULL;
```

is wrong as `ch` is of `char` type and `NULL` is not `char` type it's of `(void*)0` type.

Also  `fgetc()` returns `int` not `char`, check the manual page of `fgetc()`. It says

> fgetc() reads the next character from streamand returns it as
>   an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.

For e.g

```
int ch = 0;

while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {

    if (ch <= 255 && ch >= 0) /* what you are checking here ? Check whether it's really required */

           fputc(ch, fp1);

}
```